# How to enable SSL for virtual host on Apache Server in Ubuntu 18.04 Machine

Tags: server, apache2, php, ssl, virtualhost

I am struggling from 3-4 days to create virtual host with different PHP version. I want the main website to run on `PHP 7` (I used `PHP 7.4`) and a subdomain on `PHP 5.6`. The subdomain site is too old and does not support latest version of PHP.

However I have managed to install the both PHP versions(7.4 & 5.6) through `fcgi` method and able to configure to run two website in both version. I have checked the PHP info and it is working fine.

Now I am struggling to enable SSL for these website. I used the Cloudflare but problem is domain is not responding over `https`. After googling I have created another virtual host file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` for the SSL and put the code like below. But does not work.

After I tried to install self signed certificate and used its certificate in virtual host file. This also does not work. I followed this doc for self signed certificate.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

**Note:** Non-SSL URL is working fine. Issue is with SSL URL.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName dev.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.example.com
        # DirectoryIndex index.php
        
        SSLEngine on

        # default SSL certificate
        # SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        # SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        # self signed certificate
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

        <Directory "/var/www/dev.example.com">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        <FilesMatch \.php$>
            # For Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </FilesMatch>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.example.com_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev.example.com_access.log combined

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to connect to ```https://yourdomain/``` ?
And, did you link your file in ```sites-available``` to ```sites-enabled```?

Comment: I can see the links are available. I have used `sudo a2ensite dev.example.com.conf` command and it executed successfully. I also seen that these links are available in site-enabled through SFTP

Comment: The page keeps loading and in last it says `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: Is port 443 open?

Comment: Yes. The current server is AWS Lightsail instance. Also ufw firewall is enabled with 'Apache Full', "SSH", "OpenSSL" enabled.

Comment: Try to run ```wget --no-check-certificate -O - https://localhost/``` on your server and check if it displays the HTML output of your website. Then repeat the same with ```https://yourdomain/``` instead of ```https://localhost/```. If both work, then the problem is probably not in Apache configuration, but in the network connection to your server. You mentioned previously something about Cloudflare - that may get in the way. Try also to disable ufw for testing.

Comment: And while this may be obvious, maybe you missed it: did you restart Apache after adding your HTTPS site?

Comment: Yes. Many times

Comment: I have checked disabling the ufw. Now worked. Also `wget for localhost says
`Connecting to localhost (localhost) |127.0.0.1|:443...connected`
`OpenSSL: error:1408......:wrong version number`
`unable to establish SSL connection`.

But for my subdomain it says `Connecting to dev.example.com (dev.example.com) | 34.208.7.245|:443...` and nothing happens after this

Comment: I want to update you that I did not touched any settings for default configuration. The default configuration points to `/var/www/html` folder. While I am using domain to `/var/www/example.com` and `/var/www/devexample.com` with their own `conf` file pointing to respective directory.

Comment: Well... looks like I can't help further. Looks like some things are not interacting with each other properly in your configuration, but without knowing it in all details, it's hard to provide more help. However, networking configuration is the most probable cause of your issue. Try to investigate network config more in depth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113381/discussion-between-planethackers-and-raj).